# Error initializing classpath: No subject alternative DNS name matching services.gradle.org found. -> when running grails 3.0.1 app

Tags: grails, ssl, gradle, dns, grails-3.0

I created and ran a grails 3.0.1 app at work, but am unable to run it on my personal computer. I followed the same method of installation for grails 3.0.1 (via gvm). The problem seems to be with gradle as grails create-app worked fine. I am also able to compile the application with gradle assemble, but cannot run the application. I am using gradle 2.3.

The complete error looks as follows:

```
Error Error initializing classpath: No subject alternative DNS name matching services.gradle.org found.
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching services.gradle.org found.
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:191)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:347)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:203)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1428)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:901)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:837)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ProgressReportingDownload.download(DistributionFactory.java:177)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:59)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:46)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:122)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:116)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `https://services.gradle.org/`'s [certificate is messed up](http://discuss.gradle.org/t/urgent-ssl-apache-configuration-for-services-gradle-org-is-bad/8808)

As a **temporary** workaround you can download the gradle wrapper via http instead of https. For this you have to modify your grails wrapper configuration. I edited `build.gradle`

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
    distributionUrl = 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip'
}
```

Then generated it by issuing the command: `gradle wrapper`

After this `grails run-app` should work.

Answer (score 7):

`gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` Change this:

-from: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-all.zip`

-to: `distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-all.zip`